# Android - Socket does not close fast enough

Tags: java, android, sockets, wifimanager, onbackpressed

I've got a client-app and a server-app. The client-app is sending packets to the server-app via java.net.Socket (Protocol = TCP). On Socket.Close() my server-app instantly shows me that the connection was closed - and this is how it has to work properly. Note: the whole tcp-streaming logic is in a secondary activity, that's why I am using the onBackPressed() function to finish the whole tcp-streaming and switch to the primary activity.

Working scenario:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
      m_socket.Close();
      finish();
}
```

As explained the socket gets closed and the server **immediately** notifies that the connection was closed.

The not working scenario, as Socket.close() seems to be too slow:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
      m_socket.Close();
      m_wifiManager.disconnect();
      finish();
}
```

This scenario does only work properly in 20% of the cases. In the other 80% my server-app notifies that the connection was closed with a **big delay**. In my opinion that's because of the time the tcp-socket needs for closing - so the process gets interrupted by the wifi-connection disconnect and there could not be a proper closing for the socket *(#)*. As a proof for my opinion: *This scenario works in 100% of the cases if I debug it step-by-step. The server notifies immediately.*

What I've already tried and what also does not work properly:

- `m_wifiManager.disconnect()` in `onPause()`
- `m_wifiManager.disconnect()` in `onDestroy()`

So my questions are:

1. Is my opinion *(#)* correct? Does it lack on time for the socket-closing?
2. How do I fix this? So that tcp-socket-closing finishes properly, like in the first scenario, and after that the wifi disconnects?

Comment: Is that client or server code you're showing us?  I assume client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably with [SO_LINGER](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/SocketOptions.html#SO_LINGER) socket option:

> Specify a linger-on-close timeout. This option **disables/enables immediate return from a close()** of a TCP Socket. **Enabling this option with a non-zero Integer timeout means that a close() will block pending the transmission and acknowledgement of all data written to the peer, at which point the socket is closed gracefully**. Upon reaching the linger timeout, the socket is closed forcefully, with a TCP RST. Enabling the option with a timeout of zero does a forceful close immediately. If the specified timeout value exceeds 65,535 it will be reduced to 65,535.

It's disabled by default, your `close` call returns immediately and you disconnect wifi before the socket was actually closed. You need to call [setSoLinger](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html#setSoLinger(boolean,%20int)) to fix it:

```
m_socket.setSoLinger(true, 1);
```

Comment: actually it works perfectly for the following device on which I am debugging: `Galaxy Tab A (2016), Android Version 7.0`
But it doesn't work at all, not even once, for the following device on which I am debugging, too: `Galaxy S5, Android Version 6.0.1`
Do you know why and do you have a fix fot this?

Comment: On debugging on the Galaxy S5 I noticed that even the first scenario with the socket.close() without the disconnecting wifi connection is not working. The problem on the S5 is the m_socket.setSoLinger(true,1). Adding this line just gives both scenarios a big delay .... @Oleg You know why?

Comment: @David Try changing `1` to `0` and see if you get better results. Might be an android or vendor bug not much you can do if this is the case. Try also adding a small sleep between closing the socket and disconnecting wifi.

Comment: Results on changing to `0`. `Galaxy Tab A`: scenario 1 works everytime, scenario 2 (disconnect wifi) only works the first time, then big delay. `Galaxy S5`: scenario 1 works evrytime, scenario 2 does not work at all, always big delay!  "Try also adding a small sleep between closing the socket and disconnecting wifi." - @Oleg How can I implement this the best way?

Comment: @David Just add `Thread.sleep(100)` after you close the socket but before you disconnect wifi(also try with different numbers).

Comment: I just set Thread.sleep() on 100ms and it seems to work on all the devices/version I've tested it so far. Thank you so far! But isn't there a more neat/proper way to solve this problem? Sleep/Wait is actually not the best way for a good implementation...

Comment: @David `SO_LINGER` is the neat/proper way, if android versions or specific vendors have bugs not much to do but to work around them.

Comment: Actually, socket.setSoLinger(true, 0) solved my problem. It immediately closes the connection and allow me to start a new one.